# How to return an integer from a plpgsql function AND rollback every modifications?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

My application uses pl/pgsql functions that return integers.
The returned integer is used as a return code, to distinguish between different errors.

For example, if a function that insert datas returns -1, it means that some datas exist already and this is forbidden to try to insert the same data again. But if it returns -2, it means something else. That way the application knows the error and can display a useful error message to the user.

My problem now is that i want, at some points in the function, to return immediately when i detect an error, and rollback everything done so far in the function. If i use "raise exception", it will rollback, but not return an integer. If i use "return -1;", it will return an integer, but not rollback modifications. So i'm stuck, because obviously i can't do both

Here's a phony example function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_flight_and_passengers(
    _date timetamp,
    _name text,
    _passengers integer[]
)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    return_code integer;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO flights
    VALUES (_name);

    SELECT function_1(_date, _passengers) into return_code;
    if (return_code = -1) then
        -- [1] rollback everything done since beginning of function
        -- create_flight_and_passengers() and return -1
    end if;

    SELECT function_2(_date, _passengers) into return_code;
    if (return_code = -1) then
        -- [2] rollback everything done since beginning of function
        -- create_flight_and_passengers() and return -2
    end if;

    return 0;
END;
$$;
```

In [1] and [2] i could use *raise exception* to rollback, but when i do this i don't have a returned integer.

I could set a local variable in [1] and [2], then *raise exception*, and in EXCEPTION do tests on this variable to know where the exception come from, but this is bloated, there must be something better !

I'm not even sure you can rollback effects of a function you have called and that has terminated (function_1() and function_2() in my example)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty bizarre thing to want to do. If you really need to, you could do it like this:

```
DECLARE
  retval integer;
BEGIN
  retval := 0;
  BEGIN
    ... make my changes ...
    IF (... is something wrong? ...) THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION SQLSTATE '0U001';
    END IF;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN '0U001' THEN
      retval := -1;
  END;
END;
```

The concept here is that a `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION` block defines a *subtransaction*. A `RAISE EXCEPTION` within the block rolls back the subtransaction. We catch it at the outer level, preventing the exception from propagating outside the function and aborting the whole transaction.

See [the PL/PgSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html).

Comment: ERROR:  invalid SQLSTATE code at or near "'0U0001'". 0U0001 is not in the error codes (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/errcodes-appendix.html). How do you enable "user defined" error codes ?

Comment: @user368507 My mistake, they're five digits not six. Edited.

Comment: ok, and the correct syntax is WHEN SQLSTATE '0U001' THEN. Now it's working ! But why do you say it's pretty bizarre ? Rollback is common, but maybe getting a return code is not common ? How do you know why your function fails without return codes ?

Comment: It's much more usual to simply abort the transaction when an error condition is encountered.

Comment: @CraigRinger When you say abort what exactly do you mean?  Do you mean this http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-abort.html?

Comment: No, I just mean that rather than testing error codes you usually raise an SQL exception that gets propagated to a client side exception (or for languages without exceptions, error return) that the client handles.